# Import com.supersonicads.sdk.* Android

Tags: android, sdk, ads

I am trying to integrate ads in my Android application : I use
SupersonicAds and I followed the [documentation](http://developers.supersonic.com/hc/en-us/articles/201481051) but in the Step 3 when I have to import "com.supersonicads.sdk.*", Android Studio can't recognize the class. Do you have an idea about my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not have integrated the sdk properly. Check that you are following the steps correctly.